# Temporal noise in images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, noise, temporal

I would like to have a groundtruth image to compare the temporal denoising of Kinect data. However I cannot find a dataset/database for the same. If not a groundtruth then I would like to have a completely de-noised(temporal domain) images and an algorithm that can be used to add temporal noise to these completely denoised images, such that I can have a groundtruth image to compare efficiency of the denoising algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking on

> https://www.kaggle.com/

They have a lot of public datasets for any machine learning and data science related work. They could have what you're looking for.